# $x^2-7x+12$ Where b is negative and c is positive Factored Form

Tags: factoring

I have a problem in an old math book I was going over where I cant find a solution.

$x^2-7x+12$
Where B is negative and C is positive.

I cant seem to find anything that works where B is negative and C is positive.

Comment: What are B ,C and x?

Comment: i Can not find any $B,C$?

Comment: Doesn't matter what signs $B,C$ are (assuming you're talking about the quadratic formula).

Comment: Sorry, B and C refers to a the numbers in a trinomial like x^2 - bx + c.  In the solution it would look like (x-b...)*(x+c...)

Comment: $(x-3)(x-4)$ thats what you mean ?

Comment: @JakeDownie By the quadratic formula the roots are $3,4$ so the polynomial factors as $(x-3)(x-4)$.

Comment: Can you state the formula you're using (or describe in more detail what you're attempting to explain), like this none know what you're talking about.

Comment: @kingW3 I guess he 's talking about $ax^2+bx+c$ with $b<0,c>0$

Answer (score 1):

Note that$$x^2-7x+12 = (x-3)(x-4)$$
In general if C is negative $ x^2+Bx+C =0 $ has real solutions, since in that case  $B^2-4C>0$.

We can not say much for the case where  $C>0.$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(x-p)(x-q)=x^2-(p+q)x+pq: p,q\gt 0$ is a pattern for negative coefficient of $x$ and positive constant term.